# how to share cookies on diffrent domains in windows azure

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am working on two projects which I deployed on azure on two diffrent domains.
one is secure token service project & another is simple MVC4 project.
I have deployed these two projects on cloud.
From secure token service project it is redirecting to the MVC4 project,but after login it is not showing which user is logged in the cookies are not shared between these two applications.

please tell me how to share the cookies on azure?